# Can't resize react-chartjs-2 doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, gatsby, react-chartjs

I am trying to make a doughnut chart with react and gatsbyjs.
The chart works fine but I can not get it to use the full width of the div. It displays too small for the area reserved.

```
render (){
    return (

            <Doughnut 
                data={this.state.chartData}
                options={{
                    padding:"0px",
                    responsive:false,
                    maintainAspectRatio:false,
                    defaultFontSize:"14px",
                    width:"400",
                    height:"400",
                    legend:{
                        display:false,
                    },
                    plugins:{
                        datalabels: {
                            color:'#000000',
                            anchor: "start",
                            align:"end",
                            formatter: function(value, context) {
                                    return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
            }
                        }
                    } 
                }}
                />


        )

}
```

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html

Answer (score 14):

Have a look in the [chartjs docs](http://chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html) under *responsive*.

In the options, set `responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: true` and remove `width` and `height`.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: [10, 20, 30]
        }],
        labels: [
          'Red',
          'Yellow',
          'Blue'
        ]
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <Doughnut
        data={this.state.data}
        options={{
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-react-chartjs-2-doughnut-aszzb6?)

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @Ergun did you still need help with this question?

Comment: yes. It is answered.

Comment: @Ergun do you want to mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 5):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: [10, 20, 30]
        }],
        labels: [
          'Red',
          'Yellow',
          'Blue'
        ]
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <Doughnut
        data={this.state.data}
        options={{
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: this answer has identical code compared to the answer by @ksav, it only differs in the line `maintainAspectRatio: true` which you set to `false`. Can you motivate why your answer, that you put in almost two years later and is almost identical is a better match for the question?

Comment: because this answer worked for me and above one didn't

Answer (score 0):

This answer is same as above two answers except an extra div in the render, see below

```
render() {
    return (
     <div style={{width: '10%', height: '10%'}}>
      <Doughnut
        data={this.state.data}
        options={{
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
        }}
      />
     </div>
    )
  }
```

Since we set the **maintainAspectRatio** to **true**, we can't set the height, width to graph itself rather we can set the height, width to its parent div which allow us to modify the dimensions easily.

Happy Coding...