# React-chartjs-2 Doughnut chart canvas cannot be resized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am making a dashboard with react, I want to have doughnut charts that display some information. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-use-chartjs-to-create-charts-in-react)  that uses `chartjs` and **I have ran into an unexpected problem.**

> When I run my app, the dashboard does not display the doughnut chart,
>   however if I add a Line graph or bar chart, they display as expected

**This is the dashboard when trying to rendering a doughnut chart, I have circled what I think is the canvas for the chart**

[image]

This is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import {Pie, Doughnut} from 'react-chartjs-2';

const state = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March',
           'April', 'May'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Rainfall',
      backgroundColor: [
        '#B21F00',
        '#C9DE00',
        '#2FDE00',
        '#00A6B4',
        '#6800B4'
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [
      '#501800',
      '#4B5000',
      '#175000',
      '#003350',
      '#35014F'
      ],
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56]
    }
  ]
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Doughnut
          data={state}
          options={{
            width:"400",
            height:"400",
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            title:{
              display:true,
              text:'Average Rainfall per month',
              fontSize:20
            },
            legend:{
              display:true,
              position:'right'
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> I have looked at the following solution found on the following
>   question, but it is still not working. Note that the pie chart is also not displaying correctly, only bar and line charts display correctly

[Can't resize react-chartjs-2 doughnut chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872165/cant-resize-react-chartjs-2-doughnut-chart)

**TL;DR: Chart-js in react not showing doughnut chart but other charts work.**

Comment: the code you posted is working fine for me here https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-ritchie-ykjfb

Comment: @xplo4d well that's slightly confusing. I m not sure where I m going wrong...

Comment: @xplo4d it's fixed now, turns out I needed to upgrade my chartjs version. when I installed it,  I used the command npm install --save chart.js@^1.1.1 react react-dom, I changed it to version ^2.9.0 and now it's working